# How could I implement a refresh token that works with the implementation of the access token shown in the FastAPI docs using `python-jose`?

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi, refresh-token, python-jose

I am trying to implement a rotating refresh token with an access token (JWT) in FastAPI. However, for now I just want to get a standard refresh token implementation working with no rotation occurring.

[The FastAPI docs have an example of the implementation for the access token](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/). I have implemented this and it works fine.

But, how do I pass the refresh token in a similar fashion as a dependency to routes? Should the refresh token be placed in the same token payload when logging in as:

```
{
    "access_token": ...,
    "refresh_token": ...,
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Or should they rather be separate routes with different payloads?

Any guidance, whether they are links or code snippets, would be greatly appreciated.

In summary, how could I implement a refresh token that works with the implementation shown in the FastAPI docs linked earlier?

I want to use the `python-jose` package and not `fastapi-jwt-auth` (which is frequently suggested online). This is because `fastapi-jwt-auth` is no longer receiving support and smaller supported forks of the package are not mature yet.

Comment: Hello Harry Did you get manage to get this working? We are in the same situation regarding fastapi-jwt-auth.